# How to get JSON data from an HTTPS url using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web, https

I want to get data from a JSON file for my webpage, I searched a lot and I failed to find a request that succeeds with HTTPS.

I get this error when I run the HTML file on my machine using `jQuery.getJSON()`:

> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add this header into an Apache .conf or .htaccess file

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

You may also need to add these:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods POST, GET, OPTIONS
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-SOME-HEADER"  (additional headers you need to pass)
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "(number of seconds to cache results)"
```

Before you launch for production, you should consider restricting the origin if possible.  For example, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example.com.  If the Ajax requests will come from the same server, you should remove these headers entirely when you launch.